# Error building site: ...failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "note" not found

Tags: github-actions, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I am trying to host a website on GitHub Pages, however one of my actions keeps failing to build the site and returns this:

> Error: error building site: assemble: "/home/runner/work/Free417.github.io/Free417.github.io/content/notes/bash/basic/index.bn.md:13:1": failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "note" not found
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I don't know what is causing this, I have located the note file in question and it is present. The link to the repository for the site is here https://github.com/Free417/Free417.github.io.git. It is a forked repository with minor changes from https://github.com/hugo-toha/hugo-toha.github.io.

I've tried to host the site many times expecting the changes from my repository to be shown, however it still only shows a basic read me file from the original repository.

Comment: That failure seems to be related to your this [commit](https://github.com/Free417/Free417.github.io/commit/9b88ca3daa49ce36477c7d56d4355d80acdc4d7c) where you removed the theme inclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! I re-added the theme inclusion however the actions still failed.

Comment: You should compare the commit where it was working fine and the changes you made. It's not directly related to the GitHub Actions workflow. The issue is with the code. I just share what I found relevant from your commit history. I also checked other [forks](https://github.com/hugo-toha/hugo-toha.github.io/forks) of that repo and they had the same GHA workflow and were working fine.

Comment: The theme author stipulates on his page not to use the "main" branch as he is rewriting it? Which branch are you using? Was it working before? GitHub Pages Hugo deployment is always very unreliable.

Comment: After switching to a different working branch and updating my config file to match some other examples from people that forked the repo I was able to get it working. Thank you all so much for the help!